# How to say "running total"?

Tags: word-choice

I've looked around but haven't found a decent way to write "running total" like in the following table.

```
A  Running Total
1  1
2  3
1  4
5  9
3  12
```

Comment: Snailpane > Thanks for the link but I had looked it up there but 現在時点までの合計額 doesn't look good as a table heading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can try using:

- 累積合計 - cumulative sum
- 中間結果 - interim result (in your case a sum)

Comment: FYI: It also gets used for accumulated interest or income in the financial world.